# Adding flows: tcp-destination-port

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I want to add manual flow to my flow table using Postman/Yang models.
For testing purposes I would like that SSH traffic will be dropped, but I can't do it. Another matching works, like via only IP dest address.
Here is my XML that I've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<flow xmlns="urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory">
<hard-timeout>0</hard-timeout>
<idle-timeout>0</idle-timeout>
<priority>10</priority>
<flow-name>ssh_flow</flow-name>
<match>
    <ethernet-match>
        <ethernet-type>
            <type>2048</type>
        </ethernet-type>
    </ethernet-match>
    <ipv4-destination>192.168.4.1/24</ipv4-destination>
    <ip-match>
        <ip-protocol>6</ip-protocol>
        <ip-dscp>2</ip-dscp>
        <ip-ecn>2</ip-ecn>
    </ip-match>
    <tcp-destination-port>22</tcp-destination-port>
    <in-port>1</in-port>
</match>
<id>1</id>
<table_id>0</table_id>
<instructions>
    <instruction>
        <order>0</order>
        <apply-actions>
            <action>
                <drop-action/>
                <order>0</order>
            </action>
        </apply-actions>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
</flow>
```

Comment: Obviously I connect via SSH to 192.168.4.1/24 host, using right Open vSwitch bridge.

Comment: What is the response you get to your request ? 200 ok? or bad request? <br>

Comment: 200 Ok. I can see my flows on OVS.
As I said, another SIMPLE flows work so I think the problem is connected with wrong arguments or some lack.